# SQL Server : return coordinates for nearest time of day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

There are three tables I need information from, Machine, MachineActivity and LocationHistory. The Machine table gives information on the machine such as the MachineNumber. The MachineActivity gives information on an activity during a given day and finally the LocationHistory simply stores machine location times during a day.

I have written a view that gets out the machine information for a given day and returns their location history from before 6am. The issue is that some machines have locations after 6am, in this instance I still want the location data returned, so what I need is to return the location coordinates for the closest time available to 6am but not necessarily less than 6am.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MA.ActivityDate,
    M.MachineNumber,
    LH.Latitude,
    LH.Longitude
FROM 
    Machine M WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    MachineActivity MA WITH(NOLOCK) ON MA.MachineId = M.Id 
JOIN 
    LocationHistory LH WITH(NOLOCK) ON LH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
WHERE
    (CAST(LH.LocationTime AS Time) < '06:00:00')
```

This is where I am with it currently. I know it's likely going to need a subquery and is basically this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759743/sql-select-one-record-for-each-day-nearest-to-a-specific-time). However, I can't seem to convert this question into my scenario, the fact it's written in PostgreSQL doesn't help when this is SQL Server.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain why you are using unsupported software.

Comment: What does the "closest" time to 6am mean? The first time before, the first time after, the one with the smallest time gap? If you have the date and times `'2020-02-25T05:00:00'` and `'2020-02-25T06:59:00'` which would you want? What about if the latter was `'2020-02-25T07:00:00'`? *Side note, why are you (ab)using `NOLOCK` against all the tables? Do you understand the implications of such us? SQL Server 2008 is also completely unsupported, and has been for awhile now. You should really be looking at upgrade paths.*

Comment: Updated, 2008 was a typo and meant to be 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lateral join (`apply` in SQL Server) seems appropriate.  From what you describe:

```
SELECT MA.ActivityDate, M.MachineNumber, LH.Latitude, LH.Longitude
FROM Machine M JOIN
     MachineActivity MA 
     ON MA.MachineId = M.Id CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1)
      FROM LocationHistory LH 
      WHERE LH.MachineActivityId = MA.Id
      ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(TIME, LH.LocationTime), CONVERT(TIME, '06:00:00') ))
     ) LH;
```

Note:  You should not use `WITH (NOLOCK)` unless you fully understand what it does -- including the fact that it can return dirty, inconsistent data.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! With regards to the NOLOCK, data is written on a given day and is never used on that day. Data is only viewed historically, a day in the past, so there is no chance of bringing back dirty reads. The view is that the performance increase that the system needs that NOLOCK offers,, at this point, outweighs the potential side affects.

Comment: @cullimorer . . . `NOLOCK` does nothing if the data is not being modified.  You can test the difference -- and then remove the unnecessary directive.